# Contacted about Copyright infringement but no contact information provided?

Tags: copyright

What can you do if someone e-mails you claiming copyright infringement (i.e. that I have used some property of theirs without permission), but provide no information other than a person's name (meaning no phone, e-mail, address, nothing). How do I respond without said contact information when you know the content is yours?

Comment: If they emailed you, how do they not have an email address??? Don't respond, these are typically scams.

Comment: I just have a contact form where the contact e-mail is optional. The contact form is a way to let people contact me for any reason while still keeping their lives private. They can provide feedback, thanks, whatever. But I have to assume any legal contact would mean them providing their contact information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not obligated to do so, although you could attempt to discern the person's contact information with their name which can often be trivially done.

This doesn't appear to meet the minimum requirements for a Digital Millennium Copyright Act takedown notice.

If someone alleges that your work is infringing in a later lawsuit and you lose (which shouldn't happen if it is all your own work), and the existence of the contact form is revealed, however, it could mean the difference between willful infringement, which is subject to greater sanctions in a lawsuit, and innocent infringement, which is subject to less sanctions.

It might just be a scam and you would probably be secure in ignoring it if you know that you are not infringing.

Comment: I am not infringing. I feel confident about that. But I was concerned that people could harass an ISP, registrar etc and get my content taken down illegitimately. Anyway, i am not asking for legal advice here. I just wondered what one could do if no contact info provided.